# Can not download Ubuntu Iso file because the are recognised as virus

Tags: downloads

Can not download Ubuntu iso files,because the are shown as some kind of virus.

Please help me.

Comment: Sorry, this is too vague... Who thinks it is a virus? Windows? If so... kill the virus scanner since it is wrongly accusing files to be a virus. The ISO download is 100% virus free. I have no doubts on that; as for your system I can not guarantee it ;)

Comment: Disable the virus scanner then check yourself the ISO with md5 to verify that the source has not been compromised.

Comment: From where did you download the iso files?

Comment: What virus scanner are you using?

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the ISO file only from the [Official Ubuntu site.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
2. Try disabling your anti-virus software until the download finishes since it may be wrongly detecting the ISO file as a virus.

Answer (score 0):

I would check to make sure your download isn't infected by using a virus scanner. Always make sure you download the .iso file from the official website.